# Arduino cloning a IR signal

Tags: arduino, infrared

I have an issue here concerning Infrared and arduino, i have been disassembling various receivers and took out the IR sensor from them, but i have hard time to read any data from them.

this is my third attempt to take out a receiver from an older satellite receiver, basically what happens is nothing when i try to point any remote controll to the IR sensor, have tried various schemes but none of them is working.

would love to have some input if i do something wrong, do i need resistors or anything between the out signal and the digital input on the arduino boards or anything else?

Digital 38KHz IR Receiver, the entire IR sensor is black and seems to be encapsulated with a black molded box.

i have tried atleast 3 different arduino boards, all share the same issue on all 3 different IR sensors i tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you salvage an IR receiver from existing equipment, make sure you determine what the pinout is. They have 3 pins, and all permutations of ground, power and output seem to exist. Instead of guessing you might want to buy a receiver of a known type so you can find a datasheet, they should be < $1. My favourite yellybean is [tsop34838](http://www.voti.nl/docs/TSOP17.pdf), but the US seems to prefer other types.

Also make sure you know the operating voltage. 5V types won't work well belove 4.5V or so. I don't know whether 3.3V-only types exist, 3-5V types do exist (I prefer those).

The output of such receivers is an open-collector, the types I know have a weak internal pullup.

If you connect the receiver correctly and put a LED + 100 Ohm resistor (LED in the correct direction) from power to output, you should get the LED to light light up when you point a suitable IR source at the receiver.

[image]

Note that the above pinout is for a receiver I happen to use, yours may or may not be the same.